# RR# ComputerCraft Startup Script?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-computercraft

I am on a Resonant Rise 3 server version 3.2.7.1-RC. I'm trying to run a script on an advanced computer from ComputerCraft to control my Big Reactor and I want it to run on the computers start up so that if the computer is reset (server reset, human interaction, etc.) it keeps on running again. I know that in older versions of CC you could edit the startup file to start a program when the computer starts. But on the server the Startup file is already filled in and is not editable. I saw that it runs everything in the rom/autostart folder, but I cannot put any files in there. I tried writing in the program in rom/autostart as well as writing is elsewhere and moving/copying it in but that didn't work either.

I know that rom is for Read Only Memory but I can't see how else to auto start a script. Does anyone know how I can get the script in there or if there is any other way to have the program run on startup? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the server files? Or is this somebody elses server you are playing on?

Comment: @ydobonebi I don't run the server but I am an admin so I do have access to the server files.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do:

```
rename programname startup
```

At least, this works for me.